# Elemento visual encima de otro Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

Tengo un diseño XML de un layout en Android como se puede apreciar en la imagen:

Podrían indicarme ¿Cómo los botones pueden quedar arriba del carView?

[image: Imagen que muestra la suporpoción de elementos]

Se observa que los botones quedan debajo del webview, el cual está dentro de un cardView. Estos botones solamente aparecerían cuando sea necesario navegar a través de la página web. Tanto el cardView como los botones están en un layout tipo ConstraintLayout.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/card_view_webview"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view_webview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">

      <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    </WebView>
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes agregar los ImageButton después del cardView y para que no aparezca usa `android:visibility="gone"` y mediante código lo muestras cuando sea necesario

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_webview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            </WebView>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/card_view_webview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: layout]

Comment: Estimado. He agregado los botones en la parte inferior del documento XML y los botones siguen apareciendo detrás del cardView. No quiero ocultar el cardView ni los botones, solo que los mismos aparezcan "arriba" del cardView. Saludos.

Comment: @JuliánOviedo Edite la respuesta con una imagen, ya intentaste creando otro layout y utilizando el código que puse?, solo se muestra detrás del webview en Android studio o también en un dispositivo físico?

Comment: Tienes un detalle que no es correcto, estas usando AndroidX y ademàs las library de soporte???? android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout y androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout